# Can I set <script lang="ts"> once and global in an Svelte project?

Tags: typescript, svelte

I would like know if it is possible to set the used language once and global in an Svelte project.

My `file.svelte` would look like:

```
// Without lang="ts"
<script>
  // TypeScript Code
</script>

<div>
  // HTML Code
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature used to exist in `svelte-preprocess` but has been removed.

See [this issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess/issues/550).

Comment: That's really disappointing. I was looking forward to learning Svelte, but having TypeScript as a second class citizen isn't appealing to me. Defaults matter. Especially on green-field projects.